# How to get the definition

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is the code

```
dowl.define('owl').then(function(result){
   console.log(result)
  
})
```

It returns

```
{ definitions:
   [ { type: 'noun',
       definition:
        'a nocturnal bird of prey with large eyes, a facial disc, a hooked beak, and typically a loud hooting call.',
       example:
        'I love reaching out into that absolute silence, when you can hear the owl or the wind.',
       image_url:
        'https://media.owlbot.info/dictionary/images/owl.jpg.400x400_q85_box-403,83,960,640_crop_detail.jpg',
       emoji: '' } ],
  word: 'owl',
  pronunciation: 'oul' }
```

How do I get the definition of the word?

I tried
`result.definitions`

and it returns

```
 [ { type: 'noun',
       definition:
        'a nocturnal bird of prey with large eyes, a facial disc, a hooked beak, and typically a loud hooting call.',
       example:
        'I love reaching out into that absolute silence, when you can hear the owl or the wind.',
       image_url:
        'https://media.owlbot.info/dictionary/images/owl.jpg.400x400_q85_box-403,83,960,640_crop_detail.jpg',
       emoji: '' } ]
```

I tried
`result.definitions.definition`

It doesn't do anything. How do I get the definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitions is an array. If you want only the first result, you can use:

```
result.definitions[0].definition
```

Answer (score -1):

What `result.definitions` is is an array.. So result.definitions[0] means the first value in the array, which is an object. Take the definition from this, and that'll work.
result.definitions[0].definition